# How to make this Button Style in Android?

Tags: android, button, styles

im trying to make this Button Style in Android:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgTc6.png

But i dont want to use images, so i can modify the size of the button.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a drawable background, which is a `layer-list`, the first item should be a blue rectangle shape, the second one is your main button's color (white or grey ...), with the bottom offset about 4 or 5 pixels.